# How to integrate tess4j with Glassfish?

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, ocr, tesseract

I have successfully integrated tess4j in my java project. It was working fine. I followed the same setup in my java web project ,text extraction from image found to be empty .

I have placed tess4j,jna,ghost,jai_imageio, junit libraries in my java build path,required dll files in jdk/bin

---

> File imageDirFile = new File(imagePath);
>             try {
>                 Tesseract  instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
>
> ```
>       if (imageDirFile.isDirectory()) {
>           String[] children = imageDirFile.list();
>
>
>           for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
>               System.out.println(children[i]);
>               File imagefile=new File(imageDirFile+"\\"+children[i]);
>
>               String getresult =instance.doOCR(imagefile);
>
>             }
> ```
>
> In java project i got the final output whereas in my java web project **getresult** string found to be empty. i did not get any error message too.

I don't know where i am wrong. Please can anyone help me to figure out this problem.